# Inequality including Big-Oh-notation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

For positive a,b, I have that $x‘(t)=e^{-ax(t)}-e^{-ay(t)}+O(e^{-(a+b)x(t)})$ and can show that this has the lower bound $x‘(t)\geq O(e^{-(a+b)x(t)})\geq O(e^{-aM})$ for some positive M. I would like to deduce that $x‘(t)>0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: It does not make sense, but people will understand what you mean (though they'll probably wince). A better statement would be $f(x) = \Omega(1)$ (if you're familiar [with the $\Omega()$ counterpart to $O()$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations); careful, number theorists have a slightly different definition than computer scientists).

Comment: (question edited, the above comment does no longer apply verbatim, but the underlying point about $O()$ v. $\Omega()$ still does)

Comment: Bit why is $x‘$ eventually positive?

Comment: I commented on your use of $O()$, which was your original question; not on what you're trying to prove in the end (which is your edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you comparing the lower limits with the Big O notation? It is highly incorrect. It is used only for upper limits (bounds). As for ypur question, the Big O notation is defined for positive values only, and it will always be positive.

Comment: For positive a,b, I have that $x‘(t)=e^{-ax(t)}-e^{-ay(t)}+O(e^{-(a+b)x(t)}$ and can show that this has the lower bound $x‘(t)\geq O(e^{-(a+b)x(t)})\geq O(e^{-aM})$ for some positive M. I would like to deduce that $x‘(t)>0$ as $t\to\infty$.